# why recompile python after lib devels installed?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Why should we recompile/reinstall python to take effect on following  lib devels installed? (which was missed while first time compile).

Is there a way to avoid recompiling/reinstall python so that all third-party modules installed will remain as it is?

```
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel sqlite-devel ncurses-devel readline-devel tk-devel
```

Note: I've recompiled python twice bcoz of bzip2-devel and sqlite-devel was missing before.

Comment: Your problem is not clear to me. Yum merges binary packages and does not compile from the source, does it? So does the `yum` command force a python reinstall? And how is that a problem? Did you `pip install` python dependencies into the system's `sitepackages` dir?

Comment: For Eg: ImportError: No module named _sqlite3, this err will remain even after we install sqlite-devel and pysqlite installed. The solution is, we have to recompile python from source and install pysqlite. So, not sure why existing python wont link lib devel installed?

Comment: Does your `PREFIX` match that of the original build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the particular case of building CPython such that it can use (say) libsqlite3, if present even if it was not installed at the time CPython was built, no; you cannot do that, because CPython's build system is not designed to handle that.

In addition, in the particular case of building a CPython with (again, say) libsqlite3 and then, on a different machine, installing CPython with libsqlite3 not present, you again cannot have that.  For most of the dependencies, CPython does not currently support that sort of use case.

Both of the above are consequences of the "batteries included" mentality of CPython; it is assumed that everything that is available at all will be built into the interpreter; if its missing it's either not compatible with the given platform (say, ncurses on windows), or has been deliberately skipped for embedded systems (say, tk on robotics platform).

But that's a particular feature of just the C extensions bundled with CPython, not an intrinsic attribute of python for general c extensions.  In fact, many c extensions these days are not written that way.

Instead, a pure python wrapper, using the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) library glues a standard shared lib into the python interpreter at run-time, and can fail gracefully when that lib is not currently installed.

Comment: I like the way you said it - "consequences of the "batteries included" mentality of CPython". I think since CPython including lot of modules by default, then its setup documentation should also cover installing dependent lib devels before its source make and make install.

Answer (score 1):

Just that: When you build Python yourself, it checks for the presence of those header files. If they are not there, the build process just skips the relevant Python modules (the ones which need those headers).

When you rebuild, the build process find the header files in place and triggers the build of the relevant modules.

Comment: Thks. Is thr way to dynamically link installed lib devels to python so that avoid rebuild it again?